# Какую базу данных выбрать для телеграм бота? БД должна хранить юзеров бота и контент для юзеров бота

Tags: python, база-данных, telegram-bot, sqlite

Не могу понять с какой БД лучше делать бота.
По критериям выбора:
1 - надо чтобы БД могла хранить юзеров бота и контент для юзеров бота.
2 - контент будет разного типа (1 - цитатки из книг, 2 - ссылки на видео, например, итд)
3 - надо по запросу юзера бота из БД доставать нужны тип контента с определенным #тегом и отправлять его юзеру
4 - чем проще БД в плане настройки для этих задач - тем лучше.

Склоняюсь к SQLite3 - говорят, самая простая.
Знаю, мой вопрос очень нубско звучит. Буду признателен если просветите.

Comment: Под такое описание подходит абсолютно любая БД

Comment: Спасибо. Скорее всего я каких то важных вещей могу не видеть. Не подскажете на что обратить внимание  еще (что загуглить) чтобы свести выбор в стиле "пальцем в небо"?

Comment: Да судя по вашим требованиям подойдёт абсолютно любая бд, так что не важно что вы выберете